# Greasemonkey, Cross domain, jQuery, get() request failing with 405 "method not allowed"

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, greasemonkey

I am making cross domain jQuery `get()` and it failing with a "405 not allowed" error.

My Greasemonkey script is something like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include        http://www.foobar.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

var query = "www.foobar.com";
 $.get(
        url,
            function(response){
                alert(response);
            },
            "xml"
    );
```

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`get()` and other jQuery AJAX functions do not work cross-domain, by design. (It was/would-be a huge security hole, if they did.)

Use [GM_xmlhttpRequest()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) instead, it does allow cross-domain AJAX.

Comment: What to do on chrome, as it seems that this function doesn't work? `Uncaught ReferenceError: GM_xmlhttpRequest is not defined`

Comment: @Filype, you need to open a new question for that. [`GM_xmlhttpRequest` does work in a Chrome userscript](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=18857).  If you are using Tampermonkey you need to set `@grant GM_xmlhttpRequest`, though.

Comment: This `userscripts` workflow has been a pain. Uploading/Install  everytime there's a change. I am off to try `dotjs` as it seems to make it way easier, save file on sublime and refresh the page, your're done.